# Need to run a long php script from a browser

Tags: php, background

I created a script that gets data from some web services and our database, formats a report, then zips it and makes it available for download. When I first started I made it a command line script to see the output as it came out and to get around the script timeout limit you get when viewing in a browser. But because I don't want my user to have to use it from the command line or have to run php on their computer, I want to make this run from our webserver instead.

Because this script could take minutes to run, I need a way to let it process in the background and then start the download once the file has been created successfully. What's the best way to let this script run without triggering the timeout? I've attempted this before (using the backticks to run the script separately and such) but gave up, so I'm asking here. Ideally, the user would click the submit button on the form to start the request, then be returned to the page instead of making them stare at a blank browser window. When the zip file they exists (meaning the process has finished), it should notify them (via AJAX? reloaded page? I don't know yet).

This is on windows server 2007.

Comment: set_time_limit(0); ignore_user_abort(true); header('Location: '.$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); -- shouldn't this work in theory? It seems to still wait for the page. The idea here is to make the script run but send the user back to the previous page to be notified by ajax when the file exists.

Comment: Chris I assume that would work, but it would also kill your server on high load!

Comment: Alright, I've got it into a working form now. Using set_time_limit(0) and an ajax request it will run in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You should run it in a different process. Make a daemon that runs continuously, hits a database and looks for a flag, like "ShouldProcessData". Then when you hit that website switch the flag to true. Your daemon process will see the flag on it's next iteration and begin the processing. Stick the results in to the database. Use the database as the communication mechanism between the website and the long running process.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you have to tell what time-out you want for your process

See [PHP manual set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

You may have another problem: the time-out of the browser itself (could be around 1~2 minutes). While that time-out should be changeable within the browser (for each browser), you can usually prevent the time-out user side to be triggered by sending some data to the browser every 20 seconds for instance (like the header for download, you can then send other headers, like encoding etc...).

Answer (score 0):

Gearman is very handy for it (create a background task, let javascript poll for progress). It does of course require having gearman installed & workers created. See: http://www.php.net/gearman

Comment: While this might be a great option, I don't feel like spending time installing, configuring, and learning how to use it. I'm looking for a simpler solution, as this isn't a major component of anything, just a time saving script for another employee.

Comment: Personally, I had it set up & running from hearing of it to actual deployment of a finished process fit for production (workers, jobs and all) in about one hour, though your mileage may vary. It's essentially @just_in_case's solution, only with _less_ work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make an ajax call from the page where you want to offer the download and then just wait for the ajax call to return and also set_time_limit(0) on the other page.

Comment: Have you used this? Would this allow it to run as long as it needs? Because that is a fairly simple option if it does.